# Compatability issues with IE 11 ,how to make the page to look same when it is in preivous versions of IE with disabling the back compatability

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I am working on compatability Issues for IE11 and previous versions.
My Project is looking nice with IE compatability mode.But when I remove the compatability and set to EDGE it looks ugly.

After googled I came to know that it may required the code changes for IE11.

My pages are very bad and the css are not properly applied and alignments are at there worst.

tables are overlapped.

will it requires the code changes or will there be any generic solution.

it is written in JSP

Please help me with some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How the heck should we know?  We can't psychically see your site.

Comment: Hi Erik,Thanks for the response.I cannot give the site screen shots as  it will violates my company policies as that is not a www domain one..I am looking for a generalized solutions or suggestions or how to attack the problem.

Comment: There isn't one, since there are billions of reasons for compatibility issues, we need to see actual code that illustrates the problem (it doesn't have to be your actual company code, just code that illustrates the problem).

Comment: it's an old application .which is probably developed 10 years back standards.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the problems could be *anything* and we need actual code to solve the problem.  No matter how you argue this, it won't change this fact.  We need code that illustrates the problem in order to suggest fixes to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three things you can do:

1. Use a [legacy document mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx), e.g. add an `x-ua-compatible` header to the page with `content="IE=5"`.
2. Since you're using IE11, you can give [Enterprise mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687) (EMIE) a shot.
3. Rewrite the app to use modern standards (like the most cost effective in the long run).

The ideal answer to your question is probably somewhere along the lines of all the above.  The `x-ua-compatible` header will likely fix things in the short term, possibly buying you time to rewrite the app to use modern features and standards.  Unfortunately, document modes are [documented as deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384051(v=vs.85).aspx) and the IE team in on record as wanting to [eliminate them entirely](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/02/26/a-break-from-the-past-the-birth-of-microsoft-s-new-web-rendering-engine.aspx).  EMIE can handle situations where you're running on an intranet, but there's no guarantee that it will be available beyond the next version of Windows. In a way, it's only prolonging the inevitable.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance